# Writing/Reading from a randomaccesfile

Tags: java, randomaccessfile, eofexception

I have a project where I am to write data (strings and ints) into a binary random access file, and read the data in a separate class.  The problem I have is I'm trying to iterate through the file and read the data in a specific order (int, String, String, int), however the Strings are various byte sizes.

I am getting an EOFException but cannot figure out why.

Here is the class which writes the data. Part of the requirements is to limit the number of bytes for the Strings and catch a user defined exception if they are exceeded.

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.File;

public class QuestionBank {
   private RandomAccessFile file;
   private ArrayList <Questions> listQuestions;

   public QuestionBank(){
      file = null;
      listQuestions = new ArrayList<Questions>();      
   }

   public void storeQuestion (Questions ques) throws IOException {

      ques = new Questions(ques.getQuesIDNum(), ques.getQuestion(), ques.getAnswer(), ques.getValue());

      listQuestions.add(ques);

      byte[] quesBytes = ques.getQuestion().getBytes("UTF-8");
      byte[] ansBytes = ques.getAnswer().getBytes("UTF-8");

      try {
           file = new RandomAccessFile(new File("Question.bin"), "rw");

           long fileSize = file.length();

           file.seek(fileSize);

           file.writeInt(ques.getQuesIDNum());

           file.writeUTF(ques.getQuestion());

           for (int i = 0; i <= 50 - ques.getQuestion().length(); i++){
              file.writeByte(50);
              }              
           if (quesBytes.length > 50) {
              throw new ByteSizeException("Question has too many bytes");
              }

           file.writeUTF(ques.getAnswer());

           for (int i = 0; i <= 20 - ques.getAnswer().length(); i++){
              file.writeByte(20);
              }
           if (ansBytes.length > 20) {
              throw new ByteSizeException("Answer has too many bytes");
              }

           file.writeInt(ques.getValue()); 

           file.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("I/O Exception Found");


          } catch (ByteSizeException eb) {

            System.out.println("String has too many bytes");
          }                
    }
```

Here is the class which reads the file.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.File;

public class TriviaGame {
   public static final int RECORD = 78;
   private ArrayList<Questions> quesList;
   private int IDNum;
   private String question;
   private String answer;
   private int points;

   public TriviaGame() {
      quesList = new ArrayList<Questions>();
      IDNum = 0;
      question = "";
      answer = "";
      points = 0;
   }

   public void read(){ 
      try {
          RandomAccessFile file;

          file = new RandomAccessFile(new File("Question.bin"), "r");
          long fileSize = file.length();        
          long numRecords = fileSize/RECORD;

          file.seek(0);

          for (int i = 0; i < numRecords; i++){
             IDNum = file.readInt();
             question = file.readUTF();                                       
             answer = file.readUTF();                                              
             points = file.readInt();

             System.out.println("ID: " + IDNum + " Question: " + question + " Answer: " + answer + " Points: " + points);
         }
     file.close();

     } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e.getClass());
       System.out.println("I/O Exception found");   
    }  
  } 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you **SURE** that no data writes exceed the `RECORD` length?

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace will be better.

Comment: This looks broken: `file.writeByte(50);`  Are you sure you didn't mean to write 0 instead?

Comment: Ah, the record length is wrong.  `writeUTF()` writes two bytes for the length before it starts writing the characters.  The max length of your question is actually 52 bytes, not 50 as you were assuming.  Same for the answer field.  Documented in the [readUTF() mehtod.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF())

Comment: mark, thanks, I had no idea the writeUTF method writes 2 bytes before.  So if I change the for statement limit to <= 52 and 22, I still get the same eof exception.  I read below where I should skip the empty bytes when reading, perhaps that will help

Answer (score 0):

```
file.writeUTF(ques.getQuestion());
```

Here you have written the question.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 50 - ques.getQuestion().length(); i++){
    file.writeByte(50);
}              
if (quesBytes.length > 50) {
    throw new ByteSizeException("Question has too many bytes");
}
```

Here for some unknown reason you are padding the question to 50 bytes. Remove. Same with the answer. You are using `readUTF()` to read both of these, so all you need is `writeUTF()` to write them. No padding required.

*Or*, if you insist on this padding, you have to skip over it when reading: after the first `readUTF()`, you need to skip over the padding.

Comment: Thanks, I put the padding in there to assist in iteration in the read() method.  I've been looking for other ways to parse the data from the file but that one seemed logical.  The code isn't complete, but I intend on amending the method to read 5 random questions from the file.  My logic is if I pad the Strings with bytes then each String is 50 bytes.  The string plus the empty bytes.  But you are right, I would need to skip the remaining bytes.